# Is there a name for a "convex hull with holes"?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, terminology

If I have a (solid) 3d object, is there a name for the object created from it by taking the convex hull and subtracting from it all points that are on a straight line between any two points on the surface of the original object if that straight line is completely outside the original object (except those two points)?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/AG/4-1/4_61.pdf ? (my paper "An analogue of convexity for complements of amoebas of varieties of higher codimension, an answer to a question asked by B. Sturmfels")

Comment: Is the original object a polyhedron? Is it non-convex?

Comment: The original is an arbitrarily shaped 3d object, non-convex, with holes and/or non-contiguous.

Comment: So if you start with the surface of a smooth torus, you end up with a partially open torus, because you have removed some points of the surface surrounding the hole by lines slanting through the hole, tangent to two points? And the outer parts of the torus have no double-tangents and so remain? Whereas if it is polyhedral torus, the whole surface is removed, leaving an open polyhedral torus?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I always end up with an object that's larger than the one I started with, up to the full convex hull, if there are no "straight holes" in the object. E.g. a cube with a dent in one face will result in a cube (i.e. its convex hull), a ball with a straight round ("drilled") hole, will just stay the same, but a cube with a drilled hole with an internal cavity that's hit by the drill will become a cube with just the drilled hole (i.e. the cavity's filled except for the hole)

Comment: I'll try again. Take a cube. A line on the top face passes through two points on the surface. Is that line "completely outside the original object"? Your statement wording suggests *Yes*, in which case the surface is removed and we are left with a cube open at the boundary. If that line is not completely outside the original object, then no line passing through two points of the surface is ever completely outside, because it must touch at the two points.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I should add "except those two points", so the surface is kept.